# OpenStack multi-node setup doesn't show VM images on Dashboard

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-horizon, openstack-glance

I'm new to OpenStack and I used DevStack to configure a multi-node dev environment, currently compound of a controller and two nodes.
I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/multinode-lab.html) and used the development version of DevStack from the [official git repo](https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack). The controller was set up in a fresh Ubuntu Server 16.04.
I automated all the steps described in the docs using some scripts I made available [here](https://github.com/ifto-palmas/openstack-multi-node-installer).

The issue is that my registered VM images don't appear on the Dashboard. The image page is just empty. When I install a single-node setup, everything works fine.

When I run `openstack image list` or `glance image-list`, the image registered during the installation process is listed as below, but it doesn't appear at the Dashboard.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| ID                 | Name                     | Status | 
----------------------------------------------------------
| f1db310f-56d6-4f38 | cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk | active |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

`openstack --version` openstack 3.16.1

`glance --version` glance 2.12.1.

I've googled a lot but got no clue.
Is there any special configuration to make images available in multi-node setup?
Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to set the image as shared using
`glance image-update --visibility shared f1db310f-56d6-4f38-b5da-11a714203478`, then to add it to all listed projects (`openstack project list`) using the command `openstack image add project image_name project_name` but it doesn't work either.

**UPDATE 2**

I've included the command `source /opt/stack/devstack/openrc admin admin` inside my `~/.profile` file so that all environment variables are set. It defines the username and project name as *admin*, but I've already tried to use the default *demo* project and *demo* username.

All env variables defined by the script is shown below.

```
declare -x OS_AUTH_TYPE="password"
declare -x OS_AUTH_URL="http://10.105.0.40/identity"
declare -x OS_AUTH_VERSION="3"
declare -x OS_CACERT=""
declare -x OS_DOMAIN_NAME="Default"
declare -x OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION="3"
declare -x OS_PASSWORD="stack"
declare -x OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID="default"
declare -x OS_PROJECT_NAME="admin"
declare -x OS_REGION_NAME="RegionOne"
declare -x OS_TENANT_NAME="admin"
declare -x OS_USERNAME="admin"
declare -x OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID="default"
declare -x OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME="Default"
declare -x OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION="3"
```

When I type `openstack domain list` I get the domain list below.

```
----------------------------------------------------
| ID      | Name    | Enabled | Description        |
----------------------------------------------------
| default | Default | True    | The default domain |
----------------------------------------------------
```

As the env variables show, the domain is set as the default one.

Comment: When you login to the dashboard, and when you do openstack image list are you using the same user?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks in advance. 
I checked my setup. I'm running the CLI tools with the admin user. I included the command `source /opt/stack/devstack/openrc admin` in my `~/.profile` file, this way, it creates the `OS_USERNAME="admin"` env variable.

I tried to log in into the dashboard using the admin and demo users but no image is listed.

Comment: Can you make sure you are in the same PROJECT and DOMAIN as well.

Comment: I've just checked and it appears to be using the default domain. I provided more information at the *"UPDATE 2"* section above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing all the installation process, the issue
was due to an incorrect floating IP range defined inside the `local.conf` file.

The `FLOATING_RANGE` variable in such a file must be defined as a subnet of the node network. For instance, my controller IP is 10.105.0.40/24 while the floating IP range is 10.105.0.128/25.

I just forgot to change the `FLOATING_RANGE` variable (I was using the default value as shown [here](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/multinode-lab.html)).